# Error while installing bootloader ATmega328

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I'm trying to install a bootloader on my ATmega328P-PU. I'm trying to install it from Arduino Uno (not original). I can install all sketches. After I click "Burn bootloader" I get the following error:

```
Arduino:1.6.11 (Windows 10), Board:"Arduino/Genuino Uno"

avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega328P is 1E 95 0F
 ***failed;  
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x00 != 0x3f
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
Error while burning bootloader.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: First ensure that you have made the hardware correctly (see comment below this post).

If you need different settings for custom avr hardware the following will help:-

The best way to create a custom board definition is to create your own `boards.txt` entry in the Arduino custom hardware folder.

But less effort to learn is to try to temporarily change or add to the Arduino IDE `avr` board definitions.

The board definition (properties) are passed to the tool that burns the bootloader. All board specific properties are provided by the `boards.txt`

Edit the `[ArduinoIDE\Hardware\hardware\arduino\avr\boards.txt` with a text editor and find the Uno section.

It looks like this. Notice the `mcu`, `vid`, `pid` and `uno.bootloader.file=` settings in particular. The bootloader points to a file in `[ArduinoIDE\Hardware\hardware\arduino\avr`

```
uno.name=Arduino/Genuino Uno

uno.vid.0=0x2341
uno.pid.0=0x0043
uno.vid.1=0x2341
uno.pid.1=0x0001
uno.vid.2=0x2A03
uno.pid.2=0x0043
uno.vid.3=0x2341
uno.pid.3=0x0243

uno.upload.tool=avrdude
uno.upload.protocol=arduino
uno.upload.maximum_size=32256
uno.upload.maximum_data_size=2048
uno.upload.speed=115200

uno.bootloader.tool=avrdude
uno.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
uno.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDE
uno.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05
uno.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
uno.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F
uno.bootloader.file=optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex

uno.build.mcu=atmega328p
uno.build.f_cpu=16000000L
uno.build.board=AVR_UNO
uno.build.core=arduino
uno.build.variant=standard
```

You can add a new entry like this. The example uses a board prefix of `uno2.` but it can be any simple unique name.

Save the changes to `boards.txt` then restart the Ide:-

```
uno2.name=Arduino ATmega328P-PU

uno2.vid.0=0x2341
uno2.pid.0=0x0043
uno2.vid.1=0x2341
uno2.pid.1=0x0001
uno2.vid.2=0x2A03
uno2.pid.2=0x0043
uno2.vid.3=0x2341
uno2.pid.3=0x0243

uno2.upload.tool=avrdude
uno2.upload.protocol=arduino
uno2.upload.maximum_size=32256
uno2.upload.maximum_data_size=2048
uno2.upload.speed=115200

uno2.bootloader.tool=avrdude
uno2.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
uno2.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDE
uno2.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05
uno2.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
uno2.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F
uno2.bootloader.file=optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex

uno2.build.mcu=atmega328p
uno2.build.f_cpu=16000000L
uno2.build.board=AVR_UNO
uno2.build.core=arduino
uno2.build.variant=standard
```

note: make a copy of the .txt or grab a new one from the zip on arduino.cc if you mess it up.

Comment: Fixed! :D I must use 22pf condensator to quartz

Comment: Okay good. I think I should leave the answer because if anyone else has working hardware but needs slightly different boot loader settings for a different board it is useful. What do you think? I'll edit it to mention ensuring the hardware works first.